# Android Restlet Wrap Crashing

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, restlet

I am using Android 1.6 and restlet android edition 2.0.7...

It crashes on wrap():

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://myapp.appspot.com/restlet/");
IRestletResource r = cr.wrap(IRestletResource.class);
MyData[] ss = r.getDatas();
```

saying that

```
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.myapp.android/se.myapp.android.MyAppAndroid}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
...
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getDeclaredPublicMethods(ClassCache.java:166)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getDeclaredMethods(ClassCache.java:179)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findAllMethods(ClassCache.java:249)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getFullListOfMethods(ClassCache.java:223)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassCache.getAllPublicMethods(ClassCache.java:204)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1038)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.addAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:131)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:231)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.wrap(ClientResource.java:1541)
05-10 20:40:56.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at se.myapp.android.MyAppAndroid.onCreate(MyAppAndroid.java:61)
...
```

Interface looks like

```
public interface IRestletResource 
{
    @Get
    public MyData[] getDatas();
}
```

Serverside RestletResource looks like this:

```
public class RestletResource extends ServerResource implements IRestletResource
{
    MyData[] m_Datas;

    @Override  
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException 
    {   
        m_Datas = new MyData("carl",32);
    }   

    @Get
    public MyData[] getDatas()
    {
        return m_Datas; //return new myData("..",1); still crashes.
    }
}
```

MyData looks like this:

```
public class MyData implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String  m_Name;
    private int     m_Age;

    public MyData()
    {

    }

    public MyData(String n, int a)
    {
        m_Name = n;
        m_Age = a;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now.
It does NOT crash if i change the resource to return a String instead of MyData[].
It does still crash if i return one instance of MyData instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
```

on the client side,  aswell as

```
getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.FILE);
```

in your Application on the server side..